# How to get around big fish in the well level?

Tags: commander-keen

I started to play Commander Keen again after I saw that you can buy it in a Dos Box on Steam. Some 21 years ago I played Commander Keen 4 and now I wanted to try that again. I finished all the levels but I cannot seem to pass the big fish:

[image: Commander Keen next to the fish]

I always get eaten by it when I try to swim around:

[image: Commander Keen eaten by the fish]

Therefore I guess that you cannot really get around the fish but just have to hope that it does not come to you.

The big fish is rather fast now. My memories of this level are not that precise, but I think the fish was not that agile when I was five years old.

Could this be an issue with the clock speed of the Dos Box that gives the big fish an unfair advantage over the player? Or there there some other trick to beating this level that I have not figured out yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can use the jump key (Control) to swim a little faster. Also I realized that the fish will be sitting still for a little bit when it failed to eat Commander Keen. That and a lot of tries then actually got me to finish the level and the game.

There is also a walkthrough:

I even found a Commander Keen which has an entry for the so called [Dopefish](http://www.shikadi.net/keenwiki/Dopefish). It exactly states that the fish will pause for a bit and even eats the little fish that surround Commander Keen in that level.